# NULL from SUM function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to insert two rows into a table one of each rows contains a calculated field. Both of the statements are identical aside from P.CODE, but despite this, one of the values of the calculated field from one SQL statement is showing as null. I checked the product table which holds the one of the values used in SUM and didn't find anything out of the ordinary. Can anyone figure out why I get a value of null for one statement and not the other?

SQL

```
INSERT INTO line(inv_number, line_number, p_code, line_units, line_price)
  VALUES(1009, 1, '23109-HB', 5, (SELECT SUM(p_price * line_units) 
                                  FROM product JOIN line USING (P_CODE)
                                  WHERE p_code = '23109-HB'));

    --LINE_PRICE OF NULL BEING INSERTED HERE
INSERT INTO line(inv_number, line_number, p_code, line_units, line_price)
  VALUES(1009, 2, '14-Q1/L3', 2, (SELECT SUM(p_price * line_units) 
                                  FROM product JOIN line USING (P_CODE)
                                  WHERE p_code = '14-Q1/L3'));
```

Output

```
1009    1   23109-HB    5   49.8
1009    2   14-Q1/L3    2   (null)
```

Data from the product table used in SUM function

```
14-Q1/L3    9.00-in. pwr. saw blade 12-FEB-14   18  12  17.5    0   21344
23109-HB    Claw hammer 19-FEB-14   23  10  9.95    0.1 21225
```

**UPDATE
 I think I may have figured it out and its actually pretty obvious and kind of embarrassing. Theres a row in the "line" table that already has a p_code value of 23109-HB, so it performed the calculation on that rows' fields. However, there is no row with a p_code value of 14-Q1/L3 in the line table, so that SQL statement's line_price evaluated to NULL! Is there a way I can use SUM with data from the same insert statement or do those values already have to exist in tables? (Sorry if thats a bad question, I'm new)

Comment: Do you have this p_code = '14-Q1/L3' ?

Comment: Or perhaps line_units is 0 for p_code = 14-1/L3?

Comment: @sqluser thanks for the replies- see my edit above

Comment: What do you mean by 'SUM with data from the same insert statement'? Can you clarify that?

Comment: So I have this statement that will obviously work..
`INSERT INTO line(inv_number, line_number, p_code, line_units, line_price)
  VALUES(1009, 1, '23109-HB', 5, (SELECT SUM(p_price * 5) 
                                  FROM product
                                  WHERE p_code = '23109-HB'));`
I have the 5 in that statement twice- once to insert it into the line_units column and once to in the sum function to produce a line price. I wanted to know if I can have an sql statement that would reference the line_units within the same statement, if that makes sense.. @sqluser

Comment: answer this in an "answer" so I could hit the check and get you some credit! ;) @sqluser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirements, you can achieve that by using [WITH](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) clause:

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT p_code, p_price, line_units 
    FROM product JOIN line USING (P_CODE)
    WHERE p_code = '23109-HB'
)
INSERT INTO line(inv_number, line_number, p_code, line_units, line_price)
  SELECT 1009, 1, p_code, line_units, SUM(p_price * line_units) FROM C
```

Comment: It's cumbersome, but thats what I was going for! Thanks!